# Turning on the LED

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, led, sensormanager

My mobile phone have an LED near the front camera. It glows **red** and **green** while **charging** and for showing **missed calls**. How can I turn on this light using my application's java code? Do it fall under any sensor manger?

Comment: What sort of research/APIs have you looked into so far?  What sort of code have you tried?

Comment: @Castaglia I am using minimum API 15   and maximum API 22. I can't guess what code should I try.

Comment: As far as I know, this requires rooting your device. At least that's what apps in the app store do that allow this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [LightsManager class](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/lights/LightsManager.java#19) in the framework (running in the system server). This is what the PowerManager and NotificationManager uses to set the lights while charging/for notifications. However, it doesn't seem to be available in the public API.

You can add lights to notifications using [the `setLights()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLights%28int,%20int,%20int%29) on your Builder. But that would require you to post a notification which, depending on your usecase, may not be desirable.